# wpsd crashes on Yosemite

Tags: macos, crash, open-source

I have noticed multiple crashes in my logs of a process called wpsd. I am running OS X Yosemite v10.10.2 on a MacBook Pro. Unfortunately, I could not find what this process is used for. Anyone has a clue?

```
Process:               wpsd [12844]
Path:                  /usr/local/bin/wpsd
Identifier:            wpsd
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           wpsd [12844]
User ID:               0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `wpsd` and /usr/local/bin do not ship with OS X out of the box, you'd need to look at the creation date of the file and or check your backups to determine when the file arrived.

You could run the strings command against the file and see if that sheds any light on the process, but we might need to know more about how you install open source tools and/or add software to the system (or look at the whole dump) to know what the tool does.

Comment: strings did not help much outside from showing messages about WPS, so I would assume that wpsd stands for WPS Daemon. However, thanks for letting me know that it is not part of the standard Yosemite installation. I did a search for "wpsd" on my computer using SpotLight, and I found some information which leads me to think it got intsalled with an external network interface from RaLink.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp Good sleuthing. `sudo lsof` can show you the files and ports it has open - or you can delete it entirely and just wait to see what breaks and/or what other program complains when it's gone.